# Access kubernetes control plane via hostname in /etc/hosts on all nodes

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create a small 4 to 6 nodes bare metal cluster with 2 control planes. The special idea is to give the control plane endpoint a special hostname (for instance "currentcontrolplane") which I want to map manually in the /etc/hosts file on each node host:

```
/etc/hosts (on each node)  
192.168.1.1    currentcontrolplane

kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --control-plane-endpoint **currentcontrolplane** --upload-certs
```

If I want to change the IP address in each /etc/hosts file to the second control plane after the cluster is still initialized the cluster is not working anymore - also not after reboot all nodes. Change it back - it works.

Does anyone know the reason why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with it. If you want to create a high availability (HA) cluster which means it has multiple control planes, then it should be done differently. First it has to have at least 3 control planes if stacked `etcd` is used. Next thing is in front of control planes `loadbalancer` should be placed. I tested it with `nginx` and `haproxy` - works as well. See reference [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/) and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: I know this concept of HA cluster. But in this case I search for an only simple solution (without any external load balancer) to have the possibility to switch the control plane manually in case if one master node would crash eventually.

Comment: Were you able to join the second node? When you saying "cluster is not working" - what exactly happens? As far as I understand, in HA cluster (this is simple HA cluster because amount of control planes is more than 1), it has to be an address/DNS behind which all control planes are accessible at the same moment.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I've found the solution - oh no, so simple.

There must be a minimum of 3 control-planes for a HA cluster or if one master is down there must be at least a minimum of 2 control-planes. If there is at least only 1 master up, the whole cluster is down.

Anywhere I've found also a better solution for a bare metal cluster without load balancer.

"keepalived"

https://kvaps.medium.com/creating-high-available-baremetal-kubernetes-cluster-with-kubeadm-and-keepalived-simplest-guide-71766d5e25ae